# Cards stack view pager transformation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to achieve this: 
[image]

however, while I am able to achieve the Card sliding effect, I am unable to make the cards appear one behind the other like in this picture.

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, (page, position) -> {
                if (position >= 0) {
                    page.setScaleX(0.7f - 0.05f * position);
                    page.setScaleY(0.7f);
                    page.setTranslationX(-page.getWidth() * position);
                    page.setTranslationY(30 * position);
                }
```

Comment: check this lib https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection-android i used this to achieve above

Comment: hello,@BVtp  Did you find any solution for it ?